# How do we import sub directories in boost python

Tags: boost-python

I would like to import the package as `import ABC.xxx` using boost python
My assumption is that we have to add corresponding libraries in CMakeLists.txt and add it to target library. I am not sure whether if it's a correct way to do.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to import some other Python package into a Boost.Python-based binary module? Because linking of compiled binary libraries and Python imports are completely different things, and you don't need to mess with `CMakeLists.txt` for that. Python import in Boost.Python is as simple as this:

```
boost::python::object xxx = boost::python::import("ABC.xxx");
```

It's basically the same as the following directive in Python:

```
import ABC.xxx as xxx
```

Naturally, the directory where `ABC` package is located must be somewhere in `sys.path`.